# Transferring Files over the Internet Between iOS Devices without a Server

Tags: ios, swift, http, networking, ftp

I would like to allow two iOS devices to share large files with each other directly over the internet. I will have a simple server so that they can share IP addresses.

My initial approach was to use a HTTP server. With [GCDWebServer](https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer) I'm able to get this to work if both devices are on the same WIFI connection. However, if they are on different networks it doesn't seem to work. Also it doesn't seem to be compatible with 4G.

Is there another way this can be setup using sockets or FTP? I'm sure there must be some good open source projects on this but everything I'm finding is either so old it's too broken to fix or has similar problems GCDWebServer.

Comment: I just commented on your previous question, that might help here too. In addition to that iphone is not designed for that, if those are really large file, i suggest to create a server on cloud.

Comment: @BlindNinja that makes sense, I'll have a simple Firebase in between where IPs can be updated. This issue I am having now is really that `GCDWebServer` only seems to work with devices on the same WIFI connection. For instance if I use the service on 4G, it doesn't even give me an IP address

Comment: yes some provider use ip distribution systems to mask user's ip over provider's static ip (mostly assign to cell towers) so time to time it changes, sometimes in seconds.

Comment: Use MultipeerConnectivity?

Comment: he will still need something in middle to share his latest ip, in my suggestion it is a lot of work for just a simple system though we have much better and suitable system already developed and working awesome. use cloud/socket server etc.

Comment: maybe this can help https://www.appcoda.com/ios7-airdrop-programming-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

The library [GCDWebServer](https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer#web-based-uploads-in-ios-apps) was awesome ! Here is the Swift version::

```
import GCDWebServer
var webUploader = GCDWebUploader()

    func start() {
        let documentsPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).map(\.path).first
        
        webUploader = GCDWebUploader(uploadDirectory: documentsPath!)
        webUploader.start()
        if let serverURL = webUploader.serverURL {
            print("Visit \(serverURL) in your web browser")
        }
    }
```

[image]